# StringLength Attribute on item value in dictionary with ASP.NET Model Binder

Tags: asp.net, data-annotations, model-binding

I have a view model that looks like so:

```
   public class DeviceConfigViewModel
    {
    [StringLength(20,ErrorMessage = "Max length of 20 characters",MinimumLength = 3)]
    [DisplayName("Device Name")]
    public String DeviceName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Zone Names")]
    public Dictionary<string, string> ZoneNames { get; set; }
    }
```

how can I apply the same attribute ( `[StringLength(20,ErrorMessage = "Max length of 20 characters",MinimumLength = 3)]`) to each item/ element in the dictionary / list?

So I want to limit the `Value` of every item in the dictionary to be minimum of 3 characters long and maximum of 20 characters long.

Comment: You cannot apply the attribute, you'd have to implement your own validation logic.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to create a custom validation attribute. The below example builds on top of `StringLengthAttribute`.

```cs
public class StringValueLengthAttribute : StringLengthAttribute
{
    public StringValueLengthAttribute(int maximumLength) : base(maximumLength)
    {
    }

    protected override ValidationResult? IsValid(object? value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        // Validates and throws exception based on the range setup in the constructor
        IsValid(null);
        
        var result = ValidationResult.Success;

        if(value == null)
        {
            return result;
        }
        
        if(value is not IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> keyValuePairs)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The value must be an IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>");
        }

        var invalidKeys = keyValuePairs.Where(x => !IsValid(x.Value))
            .Select(x => $"{validationContext.MemberName}.{x.Key}")
            .ToArray();

        if (invalidKeys.Length > 0)
        {
            result = new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName), invalidKeys);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the dictionary with a list of custom models and apply validation attributes to these.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<Pair> ZoneNames { get; set; }

    public struct Pair
    {
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string Key { get; set; }

        [StringLength(20)]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

You can convert it back to a dictionary if required.

```
var zoneNames = viewModel.ZoneNames.ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);
```